# Condition with null in C# 6

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I have the following code line:

```
Project = x.Project == null ? null : new Model { ... }
```

Is there any way, in C# 6, to make this code shorter?

I have a been looking at a few ? examples but for this case I can't find a shorter solution ...

Comment: If `Project` had a `.ToModel(...)` function you could, but I don't think so as-is.

Comment: No it does not have a .ToModel() ... Yes I have been looking at the new C# 6.0 features but for this example I wasn't able to find anything that could be applied.

Comment: No, its as short as you can make it.

Comment: Nothing comes to mind, no.  We have a way to handle `x == null ? y : x` and `x == null ? null : x.y` with `??` and `?.` because they are fairly common cases.  But what you have doesn't fit into those patterns.

Comment: Can you add a ToModel extension method? Then you could make that return `null` if the input is null, and just have `Project = x.Project.ToModel()`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: making an extension method do something with `null` is pretty evil, and counts on it being an extension method. `x.Project?.ToModel()` wouldn't break if it was ever made an instance method.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Yes, it relies on it being an extension method - but I think that's okay, and it can be *really* useful to have that ability. (Imagine how much simpler `string.IsNullOrEmpty` would be to use if it had been created as an extension method...)

Comment: @JonSkeet: it *can* be useful, in limited circumstances -- but this particular method doesn't fit the bill, I think. Now that we have `?.`, it should be used, lest someone has to think twice about why `x.Project.ToModel()` does *not* require a check for `null`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert just to put my voice in, I agree with you, thats why I did my answer that way.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: I'd be reasonably happy either way. I think it partly depends on whether you can expect *all* your users to be using C# 6. It's annoying to have features which work beautifully with newer language features, but cause pain (unnecessary pain in this case) if you're stuck on an earlier version.

Comment: @JonSkeet: It's a C# 6 feature, but not tied to any version of .NET. If you're stuck, it's only because someone's too stubborn to install Visual Studio 2015, which can target older frameworks just fine. :-)

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Sure - but I see such things happen... I'd probably write it as an extension method which *does* accept null and return null (and is clearly documented as such)... and anyone using from C# 6 it is welcome to use the null conditional operator anyway. If you ever *did* need to convert it to an instance method later, you'd need to check the callers appropriately. (Even without this, it would be a behavioural change, changing from ArgumentNullException to NullReferenceException, assuming the non-null-accepting method did argument validation properly.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As-is your code is as short as it possibly can be. However if the class `Project` is based on had a `public Model ToModel(...) { }` method you could do

```
Project = x.Project?.ToModel(...);
```

UPDATE: As [JonSkeet just mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37077375/condition-with-null-in-c-sharp-6/37077485#comment61699554_37077375), you could also make `.ToModel(` a extension method.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static Model ToModel(this Project p, ...)
    {
        return new Model { ... };
    }
}
```

The syntax would still be

```
Project = x.Project?.ToModel(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, Its as short as you can make it.

However based on this code you should actually have an if condition above it to check the value of x

```
if(x != null)
    Project = x.Project == null ? null : new Model { ... }
else
    Project = null;
```

You can change this to :

```
Project = x?.Project == null ? null : new Model { ... }
```

Comment: That is not shorter ... :-)

Comment: If you have the IF conditions in your code which you didnt post then it is shorter. You can remove the IF conditions with just the use of the ? mark.

Answer (score 1):

Not shorter, but an alternative solution using Linq:

```
Model m = new Project[] { x.Project }
       .Where(p => p != null)
       .Select(p => new Model { ... })
       .FirstOrDefault();
```